# Handsontable date column sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs, handsontable

I want to sort a handsontable with date columns. I'm using Moment.js to set the database-dateformat to the german locale dateformat.

This is my code:

```
var myData = [
    {'date':moment('2012-12-01').locale('de').format('L'), 'Text':'abc'},
    {'date':moment('2015-09-12').locale('de').format('L'), 'Text':'def'},
    {'date':moment('2015-01-31').locale('de').format('L'), 'Text':'ghi'},
    ],
    container = document.querySelector('#exampleGrid');

var hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: myData,
    //cols
    colHeaders: ['Datum','Text'],
    columns: [
        {data:'date', type:'date', dateFormat:'DD.MM.YYYY', correctFormat:true},
        {data:'Text'}
        ],
    columnSorting: true,
    sortIndicator: true
});
```

Do you have any idea why it doesn't work in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d4dkrhve/)?

Comment: I think date is considered as string. Sorting based on date will not work.

Comment: hmm, but i get the date only as a string from my Database. Do i have to convert it? And how?

Comment: Even if its date, in html view is a string.

Comment: You may need to implement the sorter yourself. You would use a comparator which turns those strings into date or moment objects so that you can get the unix timestamp and compare using that. Since those are unique, ish, seconds, it should be pretty straightforward, and fast, to sort.

Comment: i have absolutely no clue, could u give me a hint or an example?